# What does "there are no validators assigned to core" mean?

Tags: parachain, stalled, polkadot-launch

What does "there are no validators assigned to core" mean and how do I fix it? I see that my parachain is stalled, I started 4 relay nodes with polkadot-launch and 3 parachains.

Answer (score 2):

If you get an error like "there are no validators assigned to core core=CoreIndex(2)", then it could well be that you're running more parachains then there are relay validators available to service them. Currently there's a minimum of 2 validators per parachain needed to be spun up.